# Why is the risk equal to the empirical risk when taking the expectation over the samples?

Tags: machine-learning, notation, definition

From Understanding Machine Learning: From theory to algorithms:

> Let $S$ be a set of $m$ samples from a set $Z$ and $w^*$ be an arbitrary vector.  Then $\Bbb E_{S \text{ ~ } D^m}[L_S(w^*)] = L_D(w^*)$.
>
> Where: $L_S(w^*) \equiv \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^ml(w^*, z_i)$ and $z_i \in S$, $L_D(w^*) \equiv \Bbb E_{z \text{ ~ }D}[l(w^*, z)]$, $D$ is a distribution on $Z$, and $l(\text{_},\text{_} )$ is a loss function.

I see that $$\Bbb E_S[L_S(w^*)] = \Bbb E_S[\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^ml(w^*, z_i)] = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m \Bbb E_S[l(w^*, z_i)]$$ and
$$L_D(w^*) = \Bbb E_z[l(w^*, z)] = \sum_{z \in Z} l(w^*, z)D(z)$$

But how are these two equal?  $\Bbb E_S$ is an expectation  over samples $S$ of size $m$ whereas $\Bbb E_z$ is an expectation over all samples in $Z$.

Comment: Hypothesis: Machine learning = Basic statistics in ridiculously over-complicated notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result is true if the sample $S$ of size $m$ is iid. In this case $S=(z_1,\dots,z_m)$ has indeed distribution $D^m$, because $D_S(z_1,\dots,z_m)=\prod_{i=1}^m D(z_i)$. Thus:

$$\mathbb E_{S \text{ ~ } D^m}[L_S(w^*)] = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m \mathbb E_{S \text{ ~ } D^m}[l(w^*, z_i)]$$

Consider now $i=1$: $\mathbb E_{S \text{ ~ } D^m}[l(w^*, z_1)]=\int l(w^*, z_1)D(z_1,\dots,z_m)dz_1\dots dz_m$ according to LOTUS. But, because of the iid hypothesis, this is actually equal to

$$\int l(w^*, z_1)D(z_1,\dots,z_m)dz_1\dots dz_m=\int l(w^*, z_1)\prod_{i=1}^m D(z_i)dz_1\dots dz_m=\prod_{i=2}^m\int D(z_i)dz_i \int l(w^*, z_1)D(z_1)dz_1 = \mathbb E_{z \text{ ~ }D}[l(w^*, z)]=L_D(w^*)$$

Of course, you can apply *exactly* the same argument for any $i=2,\dots,m$. This implies that

$$\mathbb E_{S \text{ ~ } D^m}[L_S(w^*)] = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m \mathbb E_{S \text{ ~ } D^m}[l(w^*, z_i)]=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^mL_D(w^*)=L_D(w^*)$$

A word of caution: you better be a bit flexible when it comes to notation, in reading Shai Ben-David and Shai Shalev-Shwartz. They can be a bit of a sticklers for notation: if you insist on following their pedantic notation too strictly, studying their book will take (even) more time than it should take. And you still need to read Mohri et al. book afterwards, so....

Comment: As an aside question:  Why suggest the Mohri et al. book?  Is it a more advanced treatment of the material in this book? I was under the impressions that it was relatively the same.

Comment: @OliverG nah, I was just pulling your leg  there are indeed topics which are covered better on Mohri et al., though. Vice versa, other topics are better covered on Shai X 2. Thus, if you're serious about ML theory, you should read both.

Comment: @OliverG did my post answer your question?

Comment: Ah, then I will look into that book as well as this one.  Yes, it answered my question.  I forgot that $E_{x_1, x_2, \dots}[g_1, g_2, \dots] = E_{x_1}[g_1]E_{x_2}[g_2]\dots$ in this situation.  Thank you.

Comment: @OliverG you're welcome. Since it answered your question, you can accept it as the chosen answer by clicking on the grey tick button next to the vote counter.

Comment: Ah, I clicked the bounty points but not the answer accept button.  My mistake, I'll accept it now.

Answer (score 1):

If we assume that the points in $S$ are i.i.d., then this is a direct consequence of the fact that the sample mean is an unbiased estimator of the population mean: For $X_1, \dots, X_m$ i.i.d. with $\mathbb{E}(X_i) = \mu$,

$$
\mathbb{E}\left( \bar{X}_m \right) = \mu.
$$

To obtain the result in your question, simply identify $L_S(w^*)$ with $\bar{X}_m$ and $L_D(w^*)$ with $\mu$.

This is a common issue for people getting started in machine learning — the heavy notation makes simple facts difficult to recognize. I sometimes find it useful to make a mental translation like the one above, where I discard all the subscripts and notational excesses that aren't immediately relevant to the claim in question.

Comment: Can you explain this in the notation I am using?  The book uses this notation rigorously and I want to understand it in terms of the notation.  I don't understand how the two different expectations result in the same value.

Comment: My point is that the choice of notation is arbitrary. I could have written the same fact about sample means using $Y$’s instead of $X$’s and it would make no conceptual difference. If you understand the general fact that the expectation of the sample mean equals the population mean, then you can swap in whatever random variable you want.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but I'm trying to understand the notation because it is used extensively for proofs in the book.  Can you explain it in the notation I am using?  There should be some analytical way to show that $\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m \Bbb E_S[l(w^*, z_i)]=\sum_{z \in Z} l(w^*, z)D(z)$ but I can't see it.

Comment: The "analytical" way would be to copy the standard proof that the sample mean is unbiased, making the substitutions I mention in my answer. My recommendation would be that you try this on your own, and create a new question if you're still having trouble.

Comment: If you identify $L_S$ as $\bar X_m$ and $L_D$ as $\mu$ with $\Bbb E_{z \text{ ~ }D} [l(w^*, z)] = \mu$, then we must have $\Bbb E_{z \text{ ~ } D} [l(w^*, z_i)] = \mu$.  But for the sample mean to be unbiased we must haved $\Bbb E_{z \text{ ~ } D}[\bar X_m] = \mu$.  Then we have $\frac{1}{m}m\sum_{i=1}^m \Bbb E_{z \text{ ~ } D} [l(w^*, z_i)] = \frac{1}{m}m \mu = \mu$.  But this does not answer my question, because the expectation over $L_S$ in my question is over $E_{S \text{ ~ } D^m}$.